# Converting TZ timestamp string to a given format in UTC using spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a column called lastModified with String as given below that represents time in GMT.
**"2019-06-24T15:36:16.000Z"**

I want to format this string to the format **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** in spark using scala. To achieve this, I created a dataframe with a new column *"ConvertedTS"*.
which gives incorrect time.

Machine from where I am running this is in America/New_York timezone.

```
df.withColumn("ConvertedTS", date_format(to_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("lastModified"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"), "America/New_York"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS").cast(StringType))
```

I am basically looking for formatting the result of below statement in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

```
df.withColumn("LastModifiedTS", col("lastModified"))
```

One of the ways that is currently working for me is udf but as udfs are not recommended, I was looking for more of a direct expression that I can use.

```
val convertToTimestamp = (logTimestamp: String) => {
    println("logTimeStamp: " + logTimestamp)
    var newDate = ""
    try {
      val sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
      sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
      val convertedDate = sourceFormat.parse(logTimestamp)
      val destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      destFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
      newDate = destFormat.format(convertedDate)
      println("newDate: " + newDate)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
    }
    newDate
  }

  //register for sql
  EdlSparkObjects.sparkSession.sqlContext.udf.register("convertToTimestamp", convertToTimestamp)

  // register for scala
  def convertToTimestampUDF = udf(convertToTimestamp)
  df.withColumn("LastModifiedTS", convertToTimestampUDF(col("lastModified")))
```

Thanks for help and guidance.

Comment: In addition to UDFs not being recommended I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thank you Ole. Any guidance on how to use in here?

Comment: I can write only Java code: `Instant.parse("2019-06-24T15:36:16.000Z").atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))` yields `2019-06-24 11:36:16`. [Tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there with your first `withColumn` attempt.  It just consists of an incorrect date formatting string `yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS`.  Also, `cast(StringType)` is unnecessary since `date_format` already returns a StringType column.  Below is sample code with the corrected date formatting:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "2019-06-24T15:36:16.000Z"),
  (2, "2019-07-13T16:25:27.000Z")
).toDF("id", "lastModified")

df.withColumn("ConvertedTS", date_format(to_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(
  $"lastModified", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"), "America/New_York"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
).
show(false)
// +---+------------------------+-------------------+
// |id |lastModified            |ConvertedTS        |
// +---+------------------------+-------------------+
// |1  |2019-06-24T15:36:16.000Z|2019-06-24 19:36:16|
// |2  |2019-07-13T16:25:27.000Z|2019-07-13 20:25:27|
// +---+------------------------+-------------------+
```

Additionally, if you always want UTC no matter what time zone this is executing on, you can use `java.util.TimeZone` to get that like:

```
df.withColumn("ConvertedTS", date_format(to_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(
  $"lastModified", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"), "${TimeZone.getDefault.getID}"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

(NOTE: if anyone knows how to do this with the new Java date stuff, please do edit)

Comment: oops, thanks for correcting. I didn't realize it unless I saw your reply. So, if I want the time to be the same, it is wise to use same expression above and change to GMT instead of America/New_York or is there any other recommended way.

Comment: @Dwarrior, to keep the exact `HH:mm:ss` you can simply skip the `to_utc_timestamp` transformation to disregard timezone (i.e. `date_format(to_timestamp($"lastModified", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`).

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.